# cyclic dependencies with mount points, NFS shares and symlinks

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, mount, systemd, nfs

As storage capacity is almost reached, I need to move the contents of the DOCUMENT_ROOT directory to a new disk.
As it is quite difficult to change the directory, I just would like to use the `/var/www` directory as a mount point and mount an NFS share to that directory. Then, there's no need to modify any of the apache2's configuration files and everything should run fine again.
That's the theory.

Unfortunately, when rebooting the server, the following messages are shown during the boot process:

```
systemd[1]: local-fs.target: Job media-extStorage-var-www-clients-client1-web5-log.mount/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with localfs.target/start
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping **r/www/clients/client1/web5/log
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping **Volatile Files and Directories
[ SKIP ] Ordering cycle found, skipping Local File Systems
```

Here are some parts of `/etc/fstab`:

```
/var/log/ispconfig/httpd/example.com /var/www/clients/client1/web5/log    none    bind,nobootwait    0 0
...
aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:/volume_name /media/extStorage nfs rw 0 0
```

This means, I'm mounting the NFS volume `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:/volume_name` to `/media/extStorage` as the first step.
In this external file system, there's a directory `var/www` which is referred to by the symlink `/var/www`.

I am not sure why this error message is shown, but I suspect that it's because I am mounting a directory using NFS and other mounts need this directory to be already available in order to mount other directories into it (with their targets residing on the original disk).
This would also explain the "ordering cycle" message, although there's no ordering cycle detected when checking using `systemd-analyze`.

Now my questions:

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. Is there a way to fix the setup without having to reconfigure the whole server?
3. Or: is there a way to make sure the NFS mount is already available when mounting the other file systems?

I also tried to move the whole directory `/var` to the NFS share, but that's also not an option, as the `/var` directory is needed for mounting the NFS share.
And now I'm quite lost...

I am using Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).
As hosting environment I am using ISPConfig (which also creates the entries in `/etc/fstab` and which makes it difficult to change the current setup).

Comment: Your log messages don't quite match the paths in your fstab – is it `/var/www` or is it `/media/extStorage/var/www`?

Comment: the directory where the web server is looking for its files is `/var/www`. The external storage is mounted in `/media/extStorage`. On this external storage, there's a directory `var/www` which is as an absolute path `/media/extStorage/var/www`. This directory should then be mounted to the mount point (= empty directory) `/var/www`, so that everyone who changes directory to `/var/www` in reality gets to `/media/extStorage/var/www`. This should allow me to place all the web server's files to the external storage.